# OCIDESCRIPTORFREE CRASHED INSTEAD OF RETURNING OCI_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

PROBLEM:
The call to OCIDescriptorFree(),  sometime it does not return OCI_INVALID_HANDLE rather  crash the program.
The program crashes.  Stack:
  kpufhndl, kpufhndl, OCIDescriptorFree,…, main

Example code:
OCILobLocator *lobloc = 0;
OCIDescriptorAlloc( (dvoid *)phandle->envhp, (dvoid **)&lobloc, OCI_DTYPE_LOB, 0, NULL );
…
…
…
(Maybe lost connection and then reconnect)
…
OCIDescriptorFree( (dvoid *)lobloc, OCI_DTYPE_LOB );

Reproduced at Windows Server 2012, Oracle RDBMS 12.1.0.2, Client 12.2.0.1.

According Bug 10144882, the crash of OCIDescriptorFree should be already fixed in 12.1.0.2.
(https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=97595593912668&id=10144882.8&displayIndex=2&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=17pq5lo8dx_2732)

What is the logic inner the function OCIDescriptorFree()?
When Application call OCIDescriptorFree(), how it validated the address passed by the parameter (dvoid *descp)?
Does it put it into a place(e.g, vector) when OCIDescriptorAlloc(), and then validate it according the record in the place(e.g, vector) in the following OCIDescriptorFree()?
If the validation in OCIDescriptorFree() is already enough, under what circumstances calling OCIDescriptorFree() will cause crash dump?

Comment: The bug you reference doesn't seem to match what you're seeing - you aren't freeing twice, and the stack is different. You should probably be asking Oracle about this rather than us, via a new service request.

Comment: (i) if you lose a connection, then I'm not 100% surprised that closing some resources that involve a round-trip to the DB crash (ii) work through Oracle support, as recommended. (iii) consider a simpler wrapper library on OCI, such as [OCILIB](https://github.com/vrogier/ocilib) or Oracle's [ODPI-C](https://github.com/oracle/odpi).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am aksing Oracle at the same time. But it will be a long travel as I can't reproduce it in my own environment, just in the Production env.

Comment: Regarding "(i) if you lose a connection, then I'm not 100% ...":

1. My understanding is that OCIDescriptorFree() can check the validation of of the parameter (dvoid *descp), so it should not be crashed even though the parameter is invalid.

Comment: 2. According my own test, when set the parameter(void *descp) to any memory address when calling OCIDescriptorFree(); or after calling OCIDescriptorAlloc(), then kill the old connection and reconnect, then call OCIDescriptorFree() with the memory address allocated by OCIDescriptorAlloc() before reconnected.
It will not be crashed in these two situations of calling OCIDescriptorFree(), just return error code.
So I really don't know under what situations will cause crash when calling OCIDescriptorFree() as its strong validatlion.

Comment: Regarding " (iii) consider a simpler wrapper library on OCI":
Yes, that's a good idea. But our system used its own wrapper for many years.
So it is not easy to do the replcace, any way, it is a choice.

At last, maybe you know calling OCIDescriptorFree() will crash in some special situaions, such lost connection and then reconnect, maybe others. Please kindly help to share that, thanks.